# Django migrate - django.db.utils.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: django, database, apache, sqlite

I have read the answers to similar (same) questions and the solutions have not worked for me.

I have a django application running with Apache2 webserver, and the user is set to the default www-data. Currently, www-data has full access to the db. This was working fine until couple of commits ago and I'm clueless at exactly what went wrong (Since I didn't touch the database at all during the period). Another thing to note is that makemigrations work perfectly fine, and the database is editable without errors in the django admin console.

Currently, this is my permission settings for the db:
[image]

The error message is:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: You are sure nothing else is currently working on the database or has locked the database. (https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).

Comment: I only utilise a single shell to connect to the server via SSH. I'm certain that nothing else is currently working on the database.

Comment: but it might be possible that a process had some session and locked the database, and then that program got killed and thus never unlocked the database.

Comment: I've tried restarting the ec2 instance, as well as using django extension reset_db to drop the table to create a new one. I'm still getting the same error regardless of the methods to address the issue. Please see https://pasteboard.co/JFSRzQ8.png.